# How to modify a generator value

Tags: delphi, firebird

I want to modify a generator value in Delphi with Firebird 2.5. The Statement is:
`ALTER SEQUENCE GEN_NAME RESTART WITH value` . What I want is that the value not to be a number but a variable or a parameter like:
`ALTER SEQUENCE GEN_TELAGENT_ID RESTART WITH val;` where val get a different integer value I don't know yet.

I hope I made myself understood. Sorry for my not so good English.
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

use a parameter, with your preferred components it should work.

```
myQuery.SQL.Text := 'alter sequence gen_telagent_id restart with :val';
myQuery.Params.ParamByName('val').AsInteger := val;
myQuery.ExecSQL();
```

Actual syntaxis may vary depending on the components you use to connect to Firebird.